# Problem with adding Blocks to Minecraft Mod (1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-forge

I have spent the last few hours adding a block to my Minecraft Mod. I have looked at several tutorials and none of them work. The blocks are not added to the Creative Inventory and I can't set them by command either. Unfortunately I didn't have any bugs in the console that I could show here. At some point I gave up and tried to do armor, here the same problem. On the other hand: normal items work (You can see the Item "ruby" which woked finde).

Here the code of my main class:

```
package de.thom.clashOfClasses;

import de.thom.clashOfClasses.init.ArmorMaterialList;
import de.thom.clashOfClasses.init.BlockList;
import de.thom.clashOfClasses.init.ItemList;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.inventory.EquipmentSlotType;
import net.minecraft.item.ArmorItem;
import net.minecraft.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Mod("clashofclasses")
public class ClashOfClasses {

    public static ClashOfClasses instance;
    public static final String modid = "clashofclasses";
    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(modid);

    public ClashOfClasses() {
        instance = this;

        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::setup);
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::clientRegistries);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    public void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        logger.info("Setup method complete");
    }

    public void clientRegistries(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
        logger.info("ClientRegistries method complete");
    }

    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void registerItems(final RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
            logger.info("Item Registry started");
            event.getRegistry().registerAll(
                    ItemList.RUBY,

                    ItemList.ruby_block = new BlockItem(BlockList.ruby_block,new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.MISC)).setRegistryName(BlockList.ruby_block.getRegistryName())
            );

            logger.info("Items registerd");
        }

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void registerBlocks(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
            logger.info("Block Registry started");
            event.getRegistry().registerAll
            (
                    BlockList.ruby_block = new Block(Block.Properties.create(Material.IRON).hardnessAndResistance(2.0f,3.0f).lightValue(5).sound(SoundType.METAL)).setRegistryName(location("ruby_block"))
            );

            logger.info("Blocks registerd");
        }

        private static ResourceLocation location(String name){
            return new ResourceLocation(ClashOfClasses.modid, name);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code of BlockList

```
package de.thom.clashOfClasses.init;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;

public class BlockList {
    public static Block ruby_block;
}
```

Here is the code of ItemList:

```
package de.thom.clashOfClasses.init;

import de.thom.clashOfClasses.ClashOfClasses;
import net.minecraft.inventory.EquipmentSlotType;
import net.minecraft.item.ArmorItem;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class ItemList
{
    //Test Items
    public static Item RUBY = new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.MATERIALS)).setRegistryName(location("ruby"));

    public static Item ruby_block;

    private static ResourceLocation location(String name){
        return new ResourceLocation(ClashOfClasses.modid, name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A block in the world and a “block” in an inventory are very different things. A block in the world is represented by an IBlockState, and its behavior defined by an instance of Block. Meanwhile, an item in an inventory is an ItemStack, controlled by an Item. As a bridge between the different worlds of Block and Item, there exists the class ItemBlock. ItemBlock is a subclass of Item that has a field block that holds a reference to the Block it represents. ItemBlock defines some of the behavior of a “block” as an item, like how a right click places the block. It’s possible to have a Block without an ItemBlock. (E.g. minecraft:water exists a block, but not an item. It is therefore impossible to hold it in an inventory as one.)

When a block is registered, only a block is registered. The block does not automatically have an ItemBlock. To create a basic ItemBlock for a block, one should use new ItemBlock(block).setRegistryName(block.getRegistryName()). The unlocalized name is the same as the block’s. Custom subclasses of ItemBlock may be used as well. Once an ItemBlock has been registered for a block, Item.getItemFromBlock can be used to retrieve it. Item.getItemFromBlock will return null if there is no ItemBlock for the Block, so if you are not certain that there is an ItemBlock for the Block you are using, check for null.

from https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blocks/blocks/.

I short, if everything works, your blocks shoudnt appear in your

Answer (score 0):

```
@ObjectHolder(modid)
@Mod.EventBusSunscriber(modid = modid, bus = Bus.Mod)
public class BlockInit {
  public static final Block example_block = null;

  @SubscribeEvent
  public static void registerBlocks(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
    event.getRegistry().register(new Block(Block.Properties.create(Material)).setRegistry("example_block"));
  }

  @SubscribeEvent
  public static void registerBlockItems(final RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event){ 
  event.getRegistry().register(new BlockItem(example_item, new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup)).setRegistry("example_block"));
  }
```

That works for me just replace example_block with the name of your block and add more properties if you want
for another block just repeat the event.getRegistry stuff and use the name of your new block instead of example_block.
and don't forget to do the json files